# PHP Table Unique Keys

Tags: php, database, unique

I have 3 tables.

First table is USERS,
second table is PRODUCT KEY,
third table is a join of PRODUCT KEY and USER.

Something looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE product_keys
(
id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
product_key VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(50),
email VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE user_keys
(
id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
product_key VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
user_id INT
);
```

Example: product key table has 70 keys.
If the first user register, he will receive a email with a product key. Then that first user ID and that product key will be save to the third table.

The problem is how to make the product key that had been send, won't send again and send the next one instead if a second user register.

Comment: Hi yafa, edited your question as you used the incorrect term "databases" instead of "tables" which is what you mean

Comment: How are you making your product keys? uniqid() makes a different string every time

Comment: not, those product keys will be giving by someone, I have to save them into database table keys.

Comment: @YafaSu i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. do you want unique product_key for each user.?  And is there a specific reason your `users` table has `product_keys` and the table `product_keys` has user details. or is it a typo

Comment: @YafaSu you can handle this by adding an unique key column for `product_key` in the `users` table itself. that way your application would be faster. u'll have lesser tables to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column `used` in the third table, with a default value of 0. After that, when you use a key, change it to 1.

When you select keys to assign to users, only select keys with `used=0`.

Comment: should I put it into user_keys table or pruduct_key table?

Comment: Use it in the `product_key` table. (sorry for the late answer)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear. You need to register 100 users but have only 70 keys? Well then there's no way the 71st user will get a unique one.

Otherwise, you can use `uniqid()` for generating those keys, it should return a unique string every time it is called

edit: so you just need to know which of those keys from the key table have already been used? Either put a new column in it (something like "used") which you would set to true every time it is assigned to a user (also allows you to easily get a product key that's unused), or you can simply delete the records of used keys from the table

Comment: Sorry about that, is the first of 70 people who register will get a keys. Just don't know how to solve like the first key is send. Then that key should not be send again.

Comment: I edited my answer a while ago, just put a new column that identifies used keys or delete a key every time it's used

Comment: Thanks, I would give a try.